# Stetho inspection - no data

Tags: android, okhttp, stetho

I integrated Stetho in my app as stated on the official website.
I can click on the inspect button for my running app and the chrome layout is loading fine.
Unfortunately I can't see any data in the inspect mode.
The "stetho sample" app also doesn't work.

Added:

build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.0'
```

Adjusted MainActivity:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);

        client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor())
                .build();
...
```

I can see following errormessages in my log when I click through the Chrome stetho layout.

```
D/ChromeDevtoolsServer: Method not implemented: Not implemented: Debugger.setAsyncCallStackDepth
D/ChromeDevtoolsServer: Method not implemented: Not implemented: Debugger.skipStackFrames
D/ChromeDevtoolsServer: Method not implemented: Not implemented: Runtime.enable
D/ChromeDevtoolsServer: Method not implemented: Not implemented: Worker.enable
D/ChromeDevtoolsServer: Method not implemented: Not implemented: Timeline.enable
D/ChromeDevtoolsServer: Method not implemented: Not implemented: IndexedDB.enable
D/ChromeDevtoolsServer: Method not implemented: Not implemented: Page.getNavigationHistory
D/ChromeDevtoolsServer: Method not implemented: Not implemented: Worker.setAutoconnectToWorkers
D/ChromeDevtoolsServer: Method not implemented: Not implemented: IndexedDB.requestDatabaseNames
D/ChromeDevtoolsServer: Method not implemented: Not implemented: IndexedDB.requestDatabaseNames
D/ChromeDevtoolsServer: Method not implemented: Not implemented: Page.getNavigationHistory
D/ChromeDevtoolsServer: Method not implemented: Not implemented: Page.setColorPickerEnabled
D/ChromeDevtoolsServer: Method not implemented: Not implemented: HeapProfiler.enable
D/ChromeDevtoolsServer: Method not implemented: Not implemented: ApplicationCache.enable
D/ChromeDevtoolsServer: Method not implemented: Not implemented: ApplicationCache.getFramesWithManifests
```

I read something about Proguard being the cause. If that is the cause I really can't turn off that program anywhere or let it work properly. I tried different ways I found in the internet.

e.g.
Adding to all proguard configs:

```
-keep class com.facebook.stetho.** {*;}
```

Tried to turn off proguard by:

1. deleting proguard directory out of Android SDK folder
2. setting "runProguard false" flag within build.gradle.

Help would be appreciated.